Is there a short proof of the Second Mean Value Theorm for Integrals (strong, preferably asymmetric version)
The parenthesis in the title comes from the fact that there are essentially six versions of the conclusion in what may be called 2nd Mean Value Th. for Int. - not including special variants like those using Stieltjes integrals and ignoring the different hypotheses (like continuous) on the functions involved. By a symmetric version I mean one with two integrals on the right hand side (the ends of the basic interval $[a,b]$ play then the same role), the others are asymmetric with only one integral on both sides, one can "concentrate" on one end $a$ or on the other one $b$ - this is seen as that one among $a$ and $b$ which occurs as a limit of the integral on the right hand side. Each of the two asymmetric and the symmetric versions exists in a strong and a weak version: a weak version uses as factor(s) of the integral(s) on right side a limit(s) of the monotonic function $d(a+)$ or $d(b-)$ - kind of ignoring a possible discontinuity that it might have at $a$ or $b$ - while strong versions use the values of the function $d(a)$ or $d(b)$ or any number(s) such that could be the value at $a$ or $b$ (instead of the actual ones) without contradicting the monotonicity.
So I would like to see a reference(s) to (relatively) short proof(s) of the statement:
If $f,g$ are real-valued functions defined in the compact interval $[a,b]$ ($a<b$), $g$ being $\ge 0$ and decreasing (not necess. strictly i.e. for $a \le c \le d \le b$ one has $g(c) \ge g(d)$ ) and $f$ continuous (may-be not with bounded variation), there exists a $c$ such that $a \le c \le b$ for which
$$\int _a^b f(x)g(x)dx = g(a) \int_a^c f(x)dx$$
(some authors mention that $c$ can be taken in the open interval $]a,b[$ under some extra hyp. but I don't need that)
Important: g must be allowed to not be continuous
Motivation: I need this for a proof of a result in the Fourier series (nearly the unique place for using a version of the 2nd MVT for I.) which I currently study in Y.Katznelson's book - he seems to use this implicitly without even mentioning the name of the result used, but I found in old notes from a course on F. series I attended ~ 50 years ago the name of the theorem ... and then in Wikipedia what this could mean, but no proof. In all pseudo-duplicates to be found in this website, none satisfies me. Some use Stieltjes integrals like W.Rudin in his Principles of Mathematical Analysis where this subject occupies ~ 2 to 3 pages but some extra work would be needed to get the above statement and it would not cover the case where $f$ has not bounded variation. I have found a proof but it is 11 pages (which I might reduce to ~ 5 to 7 pages by eliminating parts I don't need, still a bit long) - I guess it is correct: see https://my-calculus-web.web.app/Fourier%20Series/Second%20Mean%20Value%20Theorem%20for%20Integrals.pdf
BTW a symmetric alternative (like the one I link to above) might be OK because one can usually deduce from it easily an asymmetric version.

If $g(x)$ isn't continuous, it just won't work, the required intermediate value of $g$ might just not exist.

This is Bonnet's mean value theorem.  The usual hypotheses are that $g$ be monotone (not necessarily continuous) and $f$ be continuous.  The continuity of $f$ can even be relaxed such that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

@vonbrand with this theorem and similar versions intuition can make us think that way, but RRL must be right, and in the (long) proof that I linked to $f$ may even be just Lebesgue integrable ...

There are relatively easy proofs under the weaker assumption that $f$ is Riemann integrable (rather than continuous) and $g$ is nonnegative and decreasing.
One approach is to use Riemann sums.  It is straightforward but perhaps less elegant. Reference:  A Radical Approach to Real Analysis by Bressoud.
Another approach, that brings in the Riemann-Stieltjes integral as an intermediate step, is to introduce the function $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \,dt$. Note that $F$ is continuous given that  $f$ Riemann integrable and, hence, bounded.
The key step  relies on the fact that with both $f$ and $g$ Riemann integrable  we have
$$\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx = \int_a^b g \, dF,$$
and then using integration by parts it follows that
$$\tag{*}\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx= g(b)F(b) - g(a)\underbrace{F(a)}_{= 0}- \int_a^bF\, dg$$
Since $F$ is continuous there exists, by the first mean value theorem for integrals$, c \in (a,b)$ such that
$$\int_a^bF(x)\, dg = F(c)[g(b)-g(a)]$$
Substituting into (*) we get,
$$\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx= g(b)F(b) - F(c)[g(b)-g(a)]=g(a)\int_a^cf(x) \, dx +g(b)\int_c^bf(x) \, dx $$
Apply this result to the decreasing function $\hat{g}(x) = \begin{cases}g(x), & a\leqslant x < b\\0,&x = b \end{cases}$ to obtain
$$\int_a^b f(x) g(x) \, dx=g(a)\int_a^cf(x) \, dx $$

The fact that $\int_a^b f(x) g(x) , dx = \int_a^b g , dF$ can be proved directly using Rieman-Stieltjes sums.

Good, but I must look how to insert one of the two proofs into my context. That is nearly always the problem with proofs obtained in such a way: there might be prerequisites that are not the same for the one who asks and the one who answers. For instance I know about Stieltjes integrals but not a theorem of Integration by parts for them - the one you use looks "probably correct" for one who knows any theorem of this kind, but that isn't a proof ... I need some time to analyze this.

@UlysseKeller:  I agree. A  self-contained proof requires a justification of integration by parts for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.  It is quite easy and involves a straightforward manipulation of Riemann-Stieltjes sums, which you can find in part (2) of this answer

There are 3 results to combine: a) the one about which you added a comment (a no-name as far as I know), b) Stieltjes-integration by parts, c) first MVT for int. - for a) I have found something / for b) after trying something myself I understand now the essentials of the proof by Rudin in the book I mentioned / for c) one finds what is necessary in Rudin as well as in Bressoud (both have essentially the same argument) -> the rest being simple, I only have to clear something for b) concerning limit processes to be done

I like to consider integration processes as the effect of linear continuous maps defined in a normed vector space of functions and scalar values - real here, sometimes complex (ideas can be extended to integration of vector-valued functions); in Riemann-style integrals (incl. Stieltjes) continuity is w.r.t. the supremum-norm (leading to the topology of uniform convergence); in Lebesgue-style integrals continuity is w.r.t. $L^1$ norm. The main idea is to start with a definition on a dense subspace, and then to extend by continuity ... (continued)

(Cont. of last comment) in the case of Riemann style, one begins with characteristic functions of sub-intervals of [a,b](not a vector space) where - a discovery of mine which I have not yet seen in math. lit. - taking only intervals [a,u] (u in [a,b] ) and [a,u[ (u in ]a,b] ), these char. funct. are linearly independent, so you are free to define the linear map on them (using the g in "dg") and they generate the subspace of so-called step or staircase functions. The closure of this is the space of regulated functions (see wikipedia) so one gets integrals of such functions. I use this for a)
